# Linux: start program, check output, start another program

Tags: linux, terminal, output, process.start

Iam new to linux and need some help.

I want to write a batch script (or shell script?), which starts a program. After doing so, it has to check the output of the program (I did this earlier manually by looking to the output in the terminal window) and stop the first program and run another one.

I have no idea in which coding language (I can program in python, java, (C/C++)) to write or where to find some useful starting tips. Searched already 2~3 days.

Thanks for your help.
Gratefully,
PartyMarthy

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and [tee(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee)

Comment: Btw it is a shell script. That runs in a shell, the most common shell is bash, so it may be called a "bash script". Never a batch script though, that's what the windows equivalent (.bat) is called.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I will check out the links.